# Copy from a closed workbook to an open workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to create code to copy from an unopened excel workbook to an open book.

This is the code I've been using:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("R:\Manufacturing\First Off Log\First Off Log.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
Set y = Workbooks.Open("R:\Manufacturing\First Off Log\Analysis\First Off Log Analysis.xlsm")

x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:K").Copy

y.Sheets("Data Input").Range("A:K").PasteSpecial

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

'First Off Log Analysis' will already be open. The code above reopens the workbook and causes it to crash!

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Don't open First Off Log Analysis before running your code.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for the response! This is going to sound really silly - but how would I run a macro without Excel open? I did try to close my workbooks but keep developer open - however it shut automatically

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to run macros without opening excel: (https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning that `First Off Log.xlsm` is the workbook where the code is placed, it is opened already. Thus instead of:

`Set x = Workbooks.Open("R:\Manufacturing\First Off Log\First Off Log.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)`

write

`Set x = ThisWorkbook`

Comment: or `Workbooks("First Off Log Analysis.xlsm")` - would cover the case of it being `ActiveWorkbook` _or_ `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: I used Set y = ThisWorkbook, worked a treat thank you! @vityata